# How to infer generic type from an optional parameter in a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to have an optional parameter in a constructor, whose type is inferred as the type of a property. Unfortunately when the argument is not passed, Typescript decides the type is "unknown" rather than inferring the type is "undefined":

```
class Example<Inner> {
  inner: Inner;

  constructor(inner?: Inner) {
    if (inner) {
      this.inner = inner;
    }
  }
}

const a = new Example('foo'); // const a: Example<string>
const b = new Example(); // const b: Example<unknown>
```

Is there a way around this without having to specify the generic type or the argument?

I tried using a default value instead: `constructor(inner: Inner = undefined) {`, but then I get the error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Inner'.
> 'Inner' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Try `class Example<Inner = undefined> {  inner?: Inner; ...`?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it! Want write that as an answer?

Comment: Btw I'd recommend not to conditionally initialise that property. Instead, declare it as `inner: Inner | undefined;` and just `this.inner = inner;`

Comment: I'd also prefer that, but it doesn't work. In that case `inner` has the type `undefined` but `Inner` is not inferred as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `= undefined` to the generic type fixed the issue:

```
class Example<Inner = undefined> {
  inner: Inner;

  constructor(inner?: Inner) {
    if (inner) {
      this.inner = inner;
    }
  }
}

const a = new Example('foo'); // const a: Example<string>
const b = new Example(); // const b: Example<undefined>
```

Thanks to [Nadia Chibrikova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4434850/nadia-chibrikova) for suggesting in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573646/how-to-infer-generic-type-from-an-optional-parameter-in-a-constructor/67574552#comment119439355_67573646):

> Try class Example<Inner = undefined> {  inner?: Inner; ...?